# how can i make the frame of the alert-dialog invisible

Tags: android, frame, android-alertdialog, invisible

I made a alert Alert dialog box.I want to make the frame of the dialog box invisible.can anyone tell me how can I make this possible my code is shown below.i want to make the Alert dialogs frame invisible

```
LayoutInflater record = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View record_menu = record.inflate(R.layout.recorddialog, null);
            record = null;

            record_menu.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


            alert_box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert_box.setView(record_menu);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try following code,

```
alert_box.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in a such way...

```
    final ImageView iv24 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.kyst2);
            iv24.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```